# MongoDB: mongod not running

Tags: macos, mongodb, osx-mavericks

I just upgraded to OS X Mavericks, and it broke MongoDB (among other things...) I reinstalled MongoDB with Homebrew, and it looks fine, but when I run `mongod` in the terminal, it just logs this line:

```
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

And stops running. Any ideas on how to get it to run? Or to investigate to see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it likely that you are using a pre-2.5 MongoDB. If all else fails it looks like that "compiling with the Developer Preview version of XCode that comes with Mavericks works with MongoDB version 2.5.2."

There appears to be no GCC at all in Mavericks (by default).  Both 'g++' and 'clang' on your machine are really clang. It is because of this that if fails to read one of the file headers.

It is very unlikely that there will be support for any mongoDB versions before 2.5, so i would suggest that you update your mongoDB version. They expect 2.6+ to be working.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10644
Here is the help support ticket regarding this issue.

(OP resolved it by explicitly specifying a dbpath while using 2.5.2 (as in comments))

Comment: Thanks. Homebrew installs 2.4.9. I will try to upgrade it and see if that fixes the problem, though I'll install it another way.

Comment: I installed the development version 2.5.4 via homebrew, and now when I run mongo, nothing happens. It just goes to a new command line.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the guide provided.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Comment: I did, and the results were the same.

Comment: So is this failing when starting the server? Or trying to connect to the server?

Comment: When I start the server. I run `mongod`, and it just quietly returns a new line in the console. Should I take a look at the log file?

Comment: yeap, that would be good. Also what command are you using to launch the server?

Comment: I was using `mongod`. I finally got it to work if I explicitly specified a `dbpath`. I'm having issues with Node and the C++ bson driver, but that's another post! Thanks for the help.